# hex number of length 128 which is to be converted to binary in c#

Tags: c#, binary, hex

```
private static string GetSHA512(string strPlain)
{
     UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
     byte[] HashValue, MessageBytes = UE.GetBytes(strPlain);
     SHA512Managed SHhash = new SHA512Managed();
     string strHex = "";

      HashValue = SHhash.ComputeHash(MessageBytes);

      foreach (byte b in HashValue)
      {
          strHex += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
          //strHex += b.ToString();
      }
      int len = strHex.Length;

      //********This strHex of length 128 characters is to be converted to binary
      // ( actually 512 bit output in binary is required.)**********/
}
```

please see if anyone can help.

Comment: I presume you're asking how to represent a byte array as a string in base 2.

Comment: isn't this the same question as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892547/sorry-guys-its-hex-number-of-128-length-which-is-to-be-converted-to-binary-in-c

Comment: `foreach (byte b in HashValue)`: there you already have a list of bytes.

Comment: and The question is: How to convert the 128 long hexadecimal number to binary.

Comment: There hasn't been a hexadecimal number before you created it using `String.Format`. Before it was binary. Just take it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you're asking how to convert a byte array to a base-2 representation string:

```
byte b = 123;
string s = Convert.ToString(b, 2); // second argument is base
Console.WriteLine(s); // prints '1111011'
```

Now just walk through your byte array to create your string byte by byte.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to convert the hex string representation of the hash to a binary string representation:

```
int len = strHex.Length;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToByte(strHex.Substring(i, 1), 16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0'));
}
```